A sweet Nonodoku - Nonodoku
A new Nonodoku has arrived, the new adaptation of Nonogram to Sudoku. Remember, in this game, the numbers in each row indicate the relative order of the values in that row, but not their exact positions. The same logic applies to the columns.



 The only candidate for the third cell down in column six is 2, and the only place 3 can go in row 6 is the last cell. Then 3 and 7 must be above 2 in row 6, leading to a cascade wherein only one possible location is available for the locations of the 3's in several regions. 


 Only one place remains for 4 in the first column (taking into account the number clues on the eighth row). There are three cells outside of the blue region on column 5, which must be 3, 6, and 8 (not necessarily in that order), leaving only one spot for 9 in that column. The number clues in the second column then leave two spots for a 9, one of which is excluded by the number clues in row nine. The 9 in the first row must be in one of the last two columns per its number clues, but it cannot be in the eighth column by those number clues. This leaves only one place for 5 in the upper-right pink region, and leads to another cascade where only one spot remains for a 9 in the upper-left green region, row seven, and row nine. 


 Now, only one spot remains for a 7 in the lower-right green region (taking into account the number clues for row eight), leaving one spot for the 7 in the upper-right yellow region. Furthermore, only one spot remains for a 4 in row 1 per its number clues, leaving one spot for the 4's in row 2 and the upper-right green region. Then only one spot remains for the 2 in column two, and for the 8 in row 2, leaving one spot for the 8 in the upper-right pink region. In the middle blue region, only 1 and 4 remain, and the number clues in row seven show which permutation is correct. 


 In column four, the 1 must be in one of the bottom two rows (using number hints); but if it were in row eight then column six could not contain a 1, so it is in row nine. This determines the location of the 1 in column 6, and leaves one location for the 5 in the lower-right green region, after which column six can be completed. Then only one location remains for the 2 in row eight, leaving one location for the 2's in the upper-right yellow region and column four. Then in row eight the number clues leave only one location for 4 and 5. 


 After this, only trivial Sudoku steps remain to solve the grid almost completely, with only one use of the number clues required (namely, noting that 1 must be below 7 in column eight). 

